# The dash "search your computer and online sources" simply doens't work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation, unity-dash, idle

The dash "search your computer and online sources" simply doens't  work in Ubuntu 14.04 Similar problem occured with  12.04...
Does anybody knoes how to solve it, because i can't even open the command prompt!!!
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with two mirrored monitors.

I solved it by changing the order of the monitors (Settings->Monitors).

Comment: This answer does not seem to match the question...

Comment: In my case, that was the reason because the text input "Search your computer and online sources" even did not appear when pushing the Ubuntu icon. Of course, it can be the case of http://askubuntu.com/questions/360406/dash-not-working-after-upgrade-to-13-10 or other already solved cases, but "doesn't work" is not very specific. And Marcus, you can access a command prompt via CTRL+ALT+F1 and returning from it via CTRL+ALT+F7.